# Why doesn't pattern match on type fall through failing cases?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

See (more details, more details, more details):

```
scala> val v = Some(9).map { case lst: List[_] => lst; case i: Int => List() }
<console>:7: error: scrutinee is incompatible with pattern type;
 found   : List[_]
 required: Int
       val v = Some(9).map { case lst: List[_] => lst; case i: Int => List() }
```

Comment: What would the type of this function be? What would be the type that admits both values of type List and of Int?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `Some(9)`, the compiler **knows** that the element being mapped is an `Int`.  A `List[_]` can **never** be an `Int`, so the compiler is telling you that you are doing something that doesn't make sense.

If you want the compiler to treat it as a `Some[Any]`, you'll have to be explicit about the type:

```
val v = Some(9: Any).map { case lst: List[_] => lst; case i: Int => List() }
// v: Option[List[Any]] = Some(List())
```

or, more likely:

```
val x: Option[Any] = Some(9)
val v = x.map { case lst: List[_] => lst; case i: Int => List() }
```

But, for the record, you are probably doing something you shouldn't be and you should rethink your code.

Comment: Unfortunately this is in interpreting a parsed JSON structure (which comes back from the library as Map[String, _]). There's no way around some untyped-ness here without getting super fancy (which the standard library doesn't even do and which I'm also not inclined to do at this point).